# Using JSON to permeate hidden fields

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2.* and plain JavaScript.

**TL;DR**

> - I need help in accessing JSON parameters to fill in the value attribute in some hidden fields
> - AND a way to take the "usefulInformation" value from the JSON and permeate a modal to provide users with information.
> - Not really interested in jQuery packages, because the project is already filled with over 20 packages.

I'm fairly new to both Laravel and JSON usage, so I've been running into a problem.

I have a page with a form that I have several parameters to fill out, but the most important ones are the hidden fields I set up to automatically fill up, because those are parameters that the user is, in a way, unaware of.

When the user submits the form, the parameters are inserted in the table "`jobsCreated`" that I have in my DB, the table is basically a way to keep track of every single little thing that the enterprise is doing (buying, selling, asking for new equipment, hiring, creating accounts to enter the system, etc.). The table is a mess in a way (the table has a bit over 20 columns and 11 of those are foreign keys)and it uses a composite key to generate the "`createdJobID`".

Most of the foreign keys in this table comes from another table called "`jobsList`". I've created a JSON file that has all the parameters and elements of this table. Like this:

```
jobs.json

{
    "enterpriseID":2,
    "sectionID":1,
    "jobID":7,
    "jobDescription":"Purchase - New Mouse for Deskjob",
    "usefulInformation":"Please specify the value of the equipment",
    "urgencyLevel":"normal",
    "atendantID":0,
    "isPublic":1,
    "searchEqualFiles":0,
    "formType":21
},
{
    "enterpriseID":2,
    "sectionID":1,
    "jobID":8,
    "jobDescription":"Purchase - New Laptop/Desktop to Deskjob",
    "usefulInformation":"Inform the type of equipment and value",
    "urgencyLevel":"normal",
    "atendantID":0,
    "isPublic":1,
    "searchEqualFiles":0,
    "formType":21
},
[ it goes on for another 260++ entries, following this model]
```

Another thing the system asks in the form, is an autocomplete-ish field that lists all of the jobs in the JSON. I've come up with a JavaScript code to permeate a `datalist` with several `option` fields, like this:

```
completeForm.js

// hidden inputs
var sectionId = document.getElementById('sectionId');
var jobId = document.getElementById('jobId');
var jobTypeId = document.getElementById('typeId');
var categoryId = document.getElementById('categoryId');
var selectionOption = document.getElementsByName('selectJob');
// input autocomplete e dataList
var input = document.getElementById('selectionAutocomplete');
var dataList = document.getElementById('jobsList');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


request.onreadystatechange = function(response)
{
  if(request.readyState === 4)
  {
    if(request.status === 200)
    {
      // important bit, bolding it
      var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      for(var i = 0; i < jsonOptions.length; i++)
      {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = jsonOptions[i].jobDescription;
        dataList.appendChild(option);
      }
      
      input.placeholder = "Type the name of a job";
    }
    else
    {
      input.placeholder = "No jobs found";
    }
  }
};

input.placeholder = "Loading jobs";

request.open('GET', '{{{ url('storage/app/jobs.json') }}}', true);
request.send();
```

Which works, the JSON is being parsed. If I do `console.log(jsonOptions[i].jobDescription)`, for example, the right parameters are returned.

For my auto-complete field and hidden fields, I used the `datalist` element with the `option` element created in JavaScript.

```
// opening form, label and stuff

<input type="text" name="selectionAutocomplete" id="selectionAutocomplete" list="jobsList">
<datalist name="jobsList"> 
  // options appended here
  // elements look like this
  // <option value="Purchase - New Mouse for Deskjob"></option>
</datalist>

<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" id="sectionId">
<input type="hidden" name="jobId" id="jobId">
<input type="hidden" name="typeId" id="typeId">
<input type="hidden" name="categoryId" id="categoryId">
```

In the hidden fields, I want to set up the `value` attribute to the same one that exists (if it exists) in the JSON.
So, for example, if I check the option  `"Purchase - New Mouse for Deskjob"`, I want to access the JSON position for this particular choice and permeate the `value` attribute in the hidden fields AND trigger a modal containing the "`usefulInformation`" string.

Any type of help is welcome. Thank you in advance.